# For what values of $a \in \mathbb{R}$ is the the following matrix positive definite?

Tags: linear-algebra

For what values of $a \in \mathbb{R}$ is the the following matrix positive definite?

$\begin{bmatrix}
       a&0&-2\\
       0&a&2\\
      -2&2&a
\end{bmatrix}$

Not so basically I tried to find a method to that would help me answer this question.

I started by taking $z^TIz =\begin{bmatrix}
       a&0&-2\\
       0&a&2\\
      -2&2&a
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
       1&0&0\\
       0&1&0\\
       0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
       a&0&-2\\
       0&a&2\\
      -2&2&a
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
       a^2+4&-4&-4a\\
       -4&a^2+4&4a\\
      -4a&4a&a^2+4
\end{bmatrix}$

Not sure what i can do from here.. I then tried looking at the determinant:

$A_1 = a$

$A_2 = a^2$

$A_3 = a^3 - 8a$

Please help, I dont know how I can find the interval nor the appropriate values of $a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already on the right track. According to [Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion) a matrix is positive definite iff all upper-left corners have positive determinant. Those are exactly the three determinants you calculated.

Let's look at them in turn:

- $A_1 = a > 0 \implies a>0$. Duh.
- $A_2 = a^2 > 0 \implies a\ne 0$. This adds nothing to the first condition.
- $A_3 = a^3-8a > 0$. Since we already know that $a>0$, we can divide that inequality by $a$ to obtain $a^2-8 > 0$ Therefore we get $a>2\sqrt{2}$.

Therefore the matrix is positive if and only if $a>2\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

The matrix is positive definite, if and only if each eigenvalue is positive.

so just find the eigenvalue. $|\lambda I-A|=0$ as $\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda-a & 0 & -2\\
0 & \lambda-a & 2\\
-2 & 2 & \lambda-a
\end{bmatrix}=0$, expand it we have $(\lambda-a)^3=0$, so the eigenvalue is $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=\lambda_3=a$, we need them positive, just need $a>0$/

Comment: This answer is not correct. You forgot to invert the signs of all 2's. The answer by @celtschk is correct as is easily verified with WA: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5B%5Ba,0,-2%5D,%5B0,a,2%5D,%5B-2,2,a%5D%5D

Comment: For $a=\sqrt{2}>0$, the vector $(1,-1,\sqrt{2})^T$ is eigenvector with eigenvalue $-\sqrt{2}<0$.

Comment: Thanks, I was wrong. the equation is $\begin{vmatrix}\lambda -a&0&2\\0&\lambda-a&-2\\2&-2&\lambda-a\end{vmatrix}=0$. then the eigenvalue is $\lambda_1 = a, \lambda_2 = a-2\sqrt{2}, \lambda_3 = a+2\sqrt{2}$, we need them all positive, so $a > 2\sqrt{2}$. thanks for point out my mistakes.